# No session bound to the current context: NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, ninject

I know I can find this question on SO, with a lot of answers, but I've tried a lot of those answers and they did not work.

I am using NHibernate together with Ninject. I only get this error only after one post action, all the other actions work fine.

Here is my code to change a row of my Setting table, and my nHibernate configuration.

NHibernate/Ninject config: 
1)

```
class ArtexNinjectModule: NinjectModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// For dependency injection with Ninject
    /// </summary>
    public override void Load()
    {


        this.Bind<IRepository<Guide>>().To<GuideRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<GuideReservation>>().To<GuideReservationRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Alert>>().To<AlertRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<ReceiveAlert>>().To<ReceiveAlertRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<TourType>>().To<TourTypeRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Role>>().To<RoleRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Language>>().To<LanguageRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<GuideLanguage>>().To<GuideLanguageRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Member>>().To<MemberRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Reservation>>().To<ReservationRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Groep>>().To<GroepRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Individual>>().To<IndividualRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Address>>().To<AddressRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<BlockedDate>>().To<BlockedDateRepository>();
        this.Bind<IRepository<Setting>>().To<SettingRepository>();
        this.Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x => NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope();
        this.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory.OpenSession()).InRequestScope();

    }

}
```

2)

```
public static class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return _sessionFactory ?? (_sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory()); }
    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {

        return new Configuration()
            .Configure()
            .AddAssembly(typeof(NHibernateHelper).Assembly)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

3)

```
public class NHHttpModule : IHttpModule 
{

    protected readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Application");
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {


        context.EndRequest += ApplicationEndRequest; context.BeginRequest += ApplicationBeginRequest; 
    }      
    public void ApplicationBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory))
        {
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory.OpenSession());
            Logger.Debug("BEGIN REQUEST");
        }
    }      
    public void ApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Logger.Debug("END REQUEST");
        ISession currentSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(NHibernateHelper.SessionFactory);
        if (currentSession != null)
        {
            currentSession.Close();
            currentSession.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {  

    }
}
```

This is the action:

```
        [TransactionFilter]
        [HttpPost]
        public void Options(string maxPersonsHeadquarters, string maxPersonsTextile, string maxPerGroupHeadquarters, string maxPerGroupTextile, string deleteWithGuide, string deleteWithConfirmedGuide, string deleteWithConfirmedGroupIndi)
        {
            Setting oldSetting = _settingRepo.GetList().ToList().ElementAt(0);
            try
            {
                oldSetting.MaxPersonsHeadquarters = int.Parse(maxPersonsHeadquarters);
                oldSetting.MaxPersonsPerGroupHeadquarters = int.Parse(maxPerGroupHeadquarters);
                oldSetting.MaxPersonsTextile = int.Parse(maxPersonsTextile);
                oldSetting.MaxPersonsPerGroupTextile = int.Parse(maxPerGroupTextile);

                oldSetting.DeleteWithConfirmedGroup = bool.Parse(deleteWithConfirmedGroupIndi);
                oldSetting.DeleteWithConfirmedGuide = bool.Parse(deleteWithConfirmedGuide);
                oldSetting.DeleteWithGuide = bool.Parse(deleteWithGuide);

                _settingRepo.Edit(oldSetting);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.Error("SettingController/Option: " + e.Message );    
            }



        }
```

I hope you have enough information to solve my problem. Let me know if you need more information. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one who can help me through this? :/

Comment: For repositories - seems that you are not using session binded in http module but the session injected by ninject. Maybe you can remove the http module if you are not using it.

Comment: Then it is OK:) I thought that you are using session only in repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this.
You guys couldn't know the answer, cause it was a jQuery problem.

When the button was clicked, this went to my jQuery function. And this function did a post to my controller.

But the button input type was 'submit', so there were 2 posts to my controller.

2 posts, 1 session ==> you get a 'no session bound to the current context'-error !

Thank you all for your help.